# change saturday and sunday to 'weekend'

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') as day,
count(personID) as person
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
```

outputs

```
DAY PERSON
FRIDAY      3
SUNDAY      1
SATURDAY    2
THURSDAY    5
```

how do make it so saturday and sunday are counted as 'weekend'. So it should look like:

```
DAY PERSON
FRIDAY      3       
Weekend     3
THURSDAY    5
```

Edit:
I update the schema and it still displays the same output

```
Select case TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
when 'SATURDAY' || 'SUNDAY' then 'weekend'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') end as day,
count(personID) as person
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
```

Update: I changed it to this and it gave me half of the goal. Weekend outputs twice

```
Select 
Case TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')
when '1' then 'Monday'
when '2' then 'Tuesday'
when '3' then 'Wednesday'
when '4' then 'Thursday'
when '5' then 'Friday'
when '6' then 'WEEKEND'
when '7' then 'WEEKEND'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') end as day,
count(personID) as absenses
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')
```

Comment: Simplest option is probably a CASE statement on the result of TO_CHAR(...  If it's Saturday or Sunday then output 'WEEKEND', otherwise output the TO_CHAR(... result

Comment: @Craig ```Select TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') as day,
count(personID) as person
from AttendanceRecord
case
    when TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') = 'Saturday' || 'Sunday' then 'Weekend'
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')``` gives ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: No, that's not where the CASE goes.  The CASE goes in place of where you currently just have TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY').  Take a look at Oracle docs which also has some examples.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm  The same CASE statement will need to appear just after the "SELECT" keyword, and also after the "GROUP BY"

Comment: @Craig I was just about to correct myself. I changed it to ```Select case
when TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') = 'SATURDAY' || 'SUNDAY' then 'weekend'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') end as day,
count(personID) as person
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')``` but it still displays as Friday, saturday, sunday, thursday This  ``` Select case TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
when 'SATURDAY' || 'SUNDAY' then 'weekend'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') end as day,
count(personID) as person
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')``` is same

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on Oracle syntax, to be honest, but I would probably go with SELECT CASE TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 'weekend' WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 'weekend' ELSE TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') END AS day, ....  The only thing that might still cause an issue is case sensitivity

Comment: @Craig I also tried that, it did not work. :/

Comment: Like I said, I'm not completely up on Oracle syntax.  What is the actual output of the TO_CHAR() function?  Is it upper case or lower case?  Is it actually a fixed length string?  Really, if that CASE statement is not working, then it means the server does not believe the output of the TO_CHAR() function is exactly "SATURDAY" or "SUNDAY", so you just need to try and determine exactly how you need to word the CASE statement (otherwise, trim and change to lower case the output of TO_CHAR(), and then use just "saturday" and "sunday" in the CASE statement)

Comment: @Craig TO_CHAR() is used to change smalldatetime to a day of the week. Smalldatetime is listed as yyyy-dd-mm in the table

Comment: Yes, I know what TO_CHAR() is doing.  I'm suggesting that you need to check exactly what the string value is that it is outputting, because if the CASE statement is not working as expected, then the result of the function (for a Saturday or Sunday) must not be the actual text "SATURDAY" or "SUNDAY".  It may have some padding spaces on the end, or something else that is causing the string comparison to fail

Comment: @Craig So I figured half it it out. ```Select 
Case TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')
when '1' then 'Monday'
when '2' then 'Tuesday'
when '3' then 'Wednesday'
when '4' then 'Thursday'
when '5' then 'Friday'
when '6' then 'WEEKEND'
when '7' then 'WEEKEND'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') end as day,
count(personID) as absenses
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')``` gives the output I want. But weekend shows up twice

Comment: The GROUP BY clause also needs the same CASE statement, because otherwise you're still telling the database engine to group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `TO_CHAR(..., 'DAY')` then result is padded with spaces, i.e. for Sunday you get `"SUNDAY   "`

Try this one:

```
with t as (
    SELECT personID,
        CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american') IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN 'weekend'
        ELSE TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'fmDAY')
    END as weekDay
    FROM AttendanceRecord)
select weekday, count(personID) as person
from t
group by weekday;
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
WHEN TO_CHAR(END_TIME, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american') IN ('SAT', 'SUN') THEN 'weekend'
```

Comment: So I took this, changed it a little and got what I wanted. But now the days are separated. ```with t as (
    SELECT personID,
        CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american') IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN 'weekend'
        ELSE TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'fmDAY')
    END as day
    FROM AttendanceRecord
    group by smalldatetime, personid)
select day, count(personID) as absenses
from t
group by day, personID;```. There are two thursdays, fridays, and weekends. How do I group these?

Comment: Please open a new question. My query returns what you have asked for.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` doesn’t work like that. There are 2 forms:

```
1. CASE expression WHEN value THEN …
2. CASE WHEN condition THEN …
```

You have mixed the 2 forms together.

Either:

```
case TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
  when 'SATURDAY' then 'weekend'
  when 'SUNDAY' then 'weekend'
  else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
end
```

Or:

```
case
  when TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY') in ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') then 'weekend'
  else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
end
```

Comment: Both of these output the original ```Select  
Case  TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')
when '1' then 'Monday'
when '2' then 'Tuesday'
when '3' then 'Wednesday'
when '4' then 'Thursday'
when '5' then 'Friday'
when '6' then 'WEEKEND'
when '7' then 'WEEKEND'
else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') end as day,
count(personID) as absenses
from AttendanceRecord
group by TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')``` outputs what I need but it weeknd is duplicated

Comment: You need to then put the same whole CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause as well, then it will group the query by the same values that are being output.  So everything from "CASE" through to "END" (but don't include "as day") needs to go after GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

ISO weekday (Monday = 1) can be calculated in a *NLS* independent way as follows

`trunc(smalldatetime)-trunc(smalldatetime,'IW') + 1`

*Example*

```
select 
  smalldatetime,
  trunc(smalldatetime)-trunc(smalldatetime,'IW') + 1 iso_weekday
from AttendanceRecord
order by smalldatetime
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY; 


SMALLDATETIME       ISO_WEEKDAY
------------------- -----------
01.01.2022 00:00:00           6
02.01.2022 00:00:00           7
03.01.2022 00:00:00           1
04.01.2022 00:00:00           2
05.01.2022 00:00:00           3
```

So the only transormation is to shift the `6 and 7` to `Weekend` which is easily done be a `CASE`.

Note that I'm using CTE to aviod ugly replication between the column and `Group by`

```
with pers as (
select 
  personId,
  case when trunc(smalldatetime)-trunc(smalldatetime,'IW') + 1 in ( 6,7 ) 
  then 'Weekend'
  else TO_CHAR(smalldatetime, 'DAY')
  end as weekday
from  AttendanceRecord)
select 
 weekday, count(personID) as person 
from pers
group by weekday;

WEEKDAY                                  PERSON
------------------------------------ ----------
TUESDAY                                      14
FRIDAY                                       14
Weekend                                      30
MONDAY                                       14
WEDNESDAY                                    14
THURSDAY                                     14
```